# Binding an Array in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to bind an array to a name in a SQL statement? I'm looking for something similar to a Lisp/Haskell let-expression.

My first thought was to use a 'with' clause before the select statement that uses the array in a function call.

```
WITH thenumbers AS ARRAY(SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Bu',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Ba',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'E',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'O',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Mi',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Ho',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Wa',
                     SELECT buildingnum FROM numbers WHERE area = 'Wi')
SELECT bnorm(area,preal,thenumbers) FROM electrical_energy;
```

Two details that might inform an answer are that I'm working with Postgres 8.3 and 'numbers' is a view rather than a table.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT bnorm( area, 
              preal, 
              (select array_agg(buildingnum) 
               from numbers 
               where area in ('Bu','Ba','E','O','Mi','Ho','Wa','Wi') 
             ) 
FROM electrical_energy;
```

8.3 is pretty old and no longer supported you should *really* plan an upgrade now.